# C# Struct/ArrayList and min/max/average values

Tags: c#, struct, arraylist

I'm in the process of learning C# and I've got a little stuck with the C# Structures and finding Minimum, Maximum and Average Values from within it.

My Structure is declared as below;

```
    [Serializable]
    private struct students
    {   // Constructor Fills with default values

        public students(int x)
        {
            studentImage = " ";
            enrollmentDate = " ";
            firstName = " ";
            surname = " ";;
            englishGrade = 0;
            scienceGrade = 0;
            mathGrade = 0;
        }

        // Data types to be used in the Structure
        public string studentImage, enrollmentDate, firstName, surname;
        public int englishGrade, scienceGrade, mathGrade;

    }

   private ArrayList studentList; //This is used to work with the data
```

Within the Structure Multiple Students are listed along with their Grades for subjects.  I'm looking to cycle through the "records" and obtain the following;

- The Minimum englishGrade from within the Structure/ArrayList
- The Maximum englishGrade from within the Structure/ArrayList
- The Average englishGrade from within the Structure/ArrayList

I've looked into ordering the ArrayList but I cant use that way cause I need to order the data based on firstName.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? / Lend help?

Comment: 1) Don't use mutable structs 2) you almost certainly don't want to use a struct at all here, use a class. 3) Don't use `ArrayList`, use the gneric `List` unless you've gone back in time ten years. 4) Learn LINQ, because LINQ is awesome, and it can trivially accomplish all of these requirements.  5) There's no reason to order the structure just to take the min/max/average value from it.

Comment: Emphasis on *LINQ is awesome*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you really want to use an `ArrayList`:

```
studentList = new ArrayList();
//Fill data
var maxEnglish = studentList.
    OfType<students>().
    Max(student => student.englishGrade);
var minEnglish = studentList.
    OfType<students>().
    Min(student => student.englishGrade);
var avgEnglish = studentList.
    OfType<students>().
    Average(student => student.englishGrade);
```

After having added to your `using` directives:

```
using System.Linq;
```

But why not using a list with a generic type, such as a `List<students>`? It would make your code much more readable and efficient. Furthermore, considering that you're declaring `students` as a `struct`, each insertion in the `ArrayList` represents a boxing. It's not performant.

I would do the following edits to your code:

- Change `students` to a class and rename it to `Student`. It's conventionally better to use a class if the fields of a `struct` size, summed together, more than 16 bytes.
- Change `studentList` to a `List<Student>`.
- Remove the call to `OfType` which would be redundant.

Comment: Exactly the approach I was going to suggest. Excellent point about using List<TypeOf T>. +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had a gut feeling System.Linq would have something to do with it!

What about displaying the result in a textbox on form?

txt_minEnglish = Convert.ToString(minEnglish); dont seem to work as normal

Comment: @user1977963 You need to set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` you're operating on. In your case, `txt_minEnglish.Text = minEnglish.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone!

One last thing - I'd like to better understand the following;

var avgEnglish = studentList.
    OfType<students>().
    Average(student => student.englishGrade);

Can someone talk me through whats happening here?

I really appreciate everything.

Comment: @user1977963 `var` is an implicit variable declarator, you can replace that with `int` in the first two cases and `double` in the third one. From `studentList`, take all elements of type `students`, then calculate the max, min and average of the english grade. The `=>` token is called [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using a transparent struct type (one with all public fields) is fine, *if* the only purpose of the struct is to hold or pass around a semantically-fixed set of discrete data items, no methods write to `this` or its fields outside the constructor and property setters, the entire state of the struct is encapsulated in public fields which can legitimately take on any combination of values which would be valid for their respective types, and whose default values within the struct should match the default values in their respective types.  Your `students` type almost meets that criterion, but not quite, since it seems to represent an arbitrary selection of a student's traits, and there's no particular reason to believe that everyone who needs information about a student will need the same information.  Further, the design appears to needless hard-code the fact that each student has precisely three grades.  In some cases such assumptions are reasonable.  For example, since code which is designed to work with two-dimensional points would likely be useless with three-dimensional points, it would be fine to use a transparent structure to hold the coordinate of a 2d point.  If a 3d point is required for some purpose, code which is designed to work with 3d points won't be able to work with it, so one can simply make the 3d point a new type.  By contrast, it's reasonable to think that there might in future be some fourth kind of grade, and it would be desirable if code could "just work" with a fourth grade if one is added, but when using a struct there's not really any good way to achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use an `ArrayList`. Have a look at [generic Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

```
private List<students> studentList;
```

Usage:

```
var studentWithMaxGrade = studentList.Max(student => student.englishGrade);
var studentWithMinGrade = studentList.Min(student => student.englishGrade);
var averageGrade = studentList.Average(student => student.englishGrade);
```

You also might want to make yourself familiar with the [C# naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Rawling, Servy Be patient guys... Not so fast with the downvote button, give people time to edit the answer.

Comment: @DennisTraub Don't post an answer if you don't have an answer to the question.  Posting garbage just to get an older timestamp on your post is harmful, not helpful.  Don't post your answer until you actually have one, and most certainly don't criticize people for commenting/downvoting a post that makes no effort whatsoever to answer a question.  That's **your** fault, not ours.

Comment: If I see a useless answer I'll downvote it, especially if it's a high-rep user gaming the five-minute cutoff. Especially if it's still incorrect after the cutoff.

Comment: @Servy Whatever, good to have you guys watching the neighborhood.

Comment: I also might want to make myself familiar with the [Enumerable.Averag method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.averag.aspx), I guess.

Comment: @Rawling Why don't you just go ahead and edit an answer once you find a typo.